# How to save order made by user into a file and then displaying that after the new order is made?

Tags: python, python-3.4

this is my first question here and I am a very new Python user. I was hoping to get some  help regarding my program.

Essentially, I want the program to act as an ordering service for fast food. Once the user inputs their order, I'm trying to make it so that the order and username is stored into a file and displayed later in the program.

Here is my code so far:

```
foodMenu = {'1': 3.50, '2': 2.50, '3': 4.00, '4': 3.50,
            '5': 1.75, '6': 1.50, '7': 2.25, '8': 3.75,
            '9': 1.25}
itemTotals = {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0,'4': 0,
              '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0,
              '9': 0}

textFile = open("order.txt","r")

def main() :

menu()


def menu() :
menu = (
"""
1. Chicken Strips - $3.50
2. French Fries - $2.50
3. Hamburger - $4.00
4. Hotdog - $3.50
5. Large Drink - $1.75
6. Medium Drink - $1.50
7. Milk Shake - $2.25
8. Salad - $3.75
9. Small Drink - $1.25
"""
)
return menu

choices = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

while True:
    print(menu())

userName = input("Please enter your name")
menuNumbers = input('\nEnter the order numbers with no spaces: ')
orderTotal = 0
for i in menuNumbers:
    if i in choices:
        orderTotal += foodMenu[i]
        itemTotals[i] += 1
        print("Your total comes out to be: ",orderTotal)

        print("\nPrevious Customer:",userName "; price of previous order was",orderTotal)







main()
```

I apologize for the formatting if it's incorrect and am also aware of some of the issues with my program. (I'm completely stuck and lost however and am hoping to learn from all of you!) Thank you guys!

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Read the file into a list, make necessary changes to the items-ordered that is in the list and then just write back the list to the csv.

Comment: What isn't working? What is the error?

Comment: The issue is the file thing, not necessarily an error but something I thought i could ask the people on Stackflow. Also, I can't seem to make it so that it only prints one statement or one total order. For example, if I type in 3 numbers for three kinds of food, it'll come up with three print statements while adding the price of the previous food. I'd like only one print statement with a finalized price based off what the user typed in.